# Get direction a div is facing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code that rotates a div and I would like to figure out which direction it is facing. 
How would I find the direction a div is facing?

```
function getDirectionX(elem){
    lcelement = document.getElementById(elem);
    // find direction lcelement is facing here
    // return x;
}
function getDirectionY(elem){
    lcelement = document.getElementById(elem);
    // find direction lcelement is facing here
    // return y;
}
```

Comment: So what do you mean again?

Comment: Do you means CSS `direction`?

Comment: OP asked for X,Y direction (up, down, left and right)

Comment: You want to translate CSS rotation into X and Y coordinates? It might help to provide an example of what you're aiming for.

Comment: @showdev well im planning to put the functions in a timer so i can update the direction the div is facing every millisecond

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this help?

https://jsfiddle.net/m3130qo8/1/

Code:

```
function spinit(){
    var woah = document.getElementById('woah');
    var deg = Math.floor(Math.random() * 360) + 0;
    woah.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)'; 
    woah.style.mozTransform    = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)'; 
    woah.style.msTransform     = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)'; 
    woah.style.oTransform      = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)'; 
    woah.style.transform       = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)'; 

    var current_rotation = /[0-9]+/.exec(woah.style.transform);
    document.getElementById('woah').innerHTML=current_rotation;
}
```